# generate xml with linq to xml

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

i am trying to use linq to xml (first time:) to see if i can generate my xml file from an xsd?
ideas? links?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

[101 Linq Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746)

You should start generate DataSet from your `xsd` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a schema and want to generate a sample from it using the .NET framework then look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx. There is no LINQ to XML used however.